# Syntax highlighted code block in markdown indented list paragraph

Tags: python, markdown, mkdocs

Markdown lets me indent a paragraph twice under a list item to make it part of that list.

````md
1. List item

    Paragraph will be rendered inside of list item.

2. Other list item

    Other paragraph.

        This would be code.

3. But what about syntax highlighted code?

    ```bash
    echo "This won't work"
    ```
````

I can also indent twice as much to make code blocks.

BUT how do I use syntax highlighted code blocks such as `these` inside a list paragraph? Is it at all possible?

In my situation I'm using mkdocs, a python static HTML generator using markdown.

Background on why I'm asking is because such lists actually make for a really nice design when you're writing step by step guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```md
3. But what about syntax highlighted code?

~~~~ bash
echo "This won't work"
~~~~
```

It renders like this in Firefox (using [Stackedit](https://stackedit.io/)):

[image]

Comment: That does work very well, I tried it in dillinger before your edit and now in stackedit too. In fact they both can also render my first attempt using ``` too. So this now has become a mkdocs issue. Thanks for your solution and confirmation that markdown does indeed support this!